# Finding redundancy in table

Tags: database, database-design

I am having following database :

[image]

Now I want to identify the major data redundancy problems exhibited by this file structure. Also are there some changes that can be made 
for the Employee_Name and Employee_Phone? I am new to database and all, so please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd advise you to keep a table for your projects and a separate table for your Employees. I don't know what you're trying to accomplish so maybe Employees is really a People table with a flag to indicate an employee. Then I'd keep a separate table as well (I'd call it Activity) which links to Projects and Employees and contains HoursWorked and maybe some notes. Then to get what you've got here I'd create a view that joins the tables together and groups by Project and Employee and sums up the hours worked.

Somthing like:

```
Create table Project
(
  ID int not null,
  ProjectCode nvarchar(32),
  ProjectName nvarchar(128)
);

Create table Employee
(
  ID int not null,
  EmployeeName nvarchar(128),
  PhoneNumber nvarchar(32)
);

Create table Activity
(
  ID int not null,
  EmployeeID int not null,
  ProjectID int not null,
  Hours decimal,
  Notes nvarchar(MAX)
);

Create View HoursWorked AS 
SELECT
  P.ProjectCode,
  P.ProjectName,
  E.EmployeeName,
  SUM(A.Hours) AS HoursWorked,
  E.PhoneNumber
 FROM
   Activity A
   INNER JOIN Project P ON P.ID = A.ProjectID
   INNER JOIN Employee E ON E.ID = A.EmployeeID
 GROUP BY
  P.ProjectCode,
  P.ProjectName,
  E.EmployeeName,
  E.PhoneNumber
 ;
```

You'd have to create the foreign key relationships and all. Also I didn't test this out so maybe I messed up some of the syntax but the idea's there.

Comment: Can you please mention the redundancies before posting solution to elminate it ?

Comment: Well - if you keep repeating employees or projects in the table you'll end up with those data items again and again. But if you separate those out you'll need a separate place to store hours. Hence my deign above.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using three tables: projects, people, work.

Projects would hold code and name

People would hold name and phone

Work would contain entries for each work event, with an interval for time worked, the primary key for the person who worked, and the primary key for the project that person worked on.

Then, to output a table like your initial one, you would select from all three. If you need an example of such a query, please comment and I will author it.

Comment: Please add example . Also what about Employee_Name and Employee_Phone ? Any changes for it ?

Comment: Also please add explanation that why are you breaking the table ? You posted solution to eliminate it thats fine, but what was cause  ? Add that

Comment: Brett elaborated on the same concept, I would defer to his answer, my code would look similar. As far as redundancies, you want to reference anything repetitive, so that you don't store something like a person's name multiple times. That makes the database slower, less efficient, and more difficult to modify.